# How to set up Facebook Dynamic ads based on first-party data in Salesforce

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, facebook, commerce-cloud

I've read that it is possible to set up Facebook Dynamic ads based on web activity and also CRM data (email engagement) from within Salesforce - with no manual data upload required.

I'm a little confused where this would be configured, Marketing Cloud or Commerce Cloud?

Has anyone else done anything similar? Any help or advice would be a massive help!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to utilise [Advertising Studio](https://www.salesforce.com/products/marketing-cloud/digital-advertising/) which indeed is allowing you to utilise the data from Marketing Cloud to execute campaigns on a.o. Facebook. It is usually an additional feature, purchased separately on top of your standard Marketing Cloud.

Comment: You're welcome @Bedders2020 - remember to mark the answer as accepted, so others can benefit from it.

Comment: Cheers will do! Just going back to the original question. If I wanted to add Facebook ad campaigns to a journey in journey builder, would this also require advertising studio to be enabled/purchased?

Comment: Yes, with Advertising Studio, you will have the ability of adding and removing the individual subscriber in an Audience activity in JB